# Chandler Start-Up Script /bin/bash vs /bin/sh

Tags: bash, shell, init.d

Have a Chandler install that worked fine for a number of months, but recently when I went to connect to the server, I noticed it wasn't running.

SSHing in, confirmed it isn't running, so I go to manually restart via my chandler startup script (`/etc/init.d/chandler`) that worked perfectly for months and months through various reboots, etc and I get the following error:

```
/chandler/bin/osafsrvctl: 24: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Now, if I go directly to `/chandler/bin/osafsrvctl` an run the following as root `/chandler/bin/osafsrvctl start`, it starts without error.

Some searching online led me to believe this is something to do with Chandler needing /bin/bash to start properly as the startup script is Bash. Fine. Check the `/chandler/bin/osafsrvctl` file and it is indeed using `/bin/bash`. Changing the init.d startup script to also use /bin/bash did nothing, get the same error. Here is the `/etc/init.d/chandler` script that generates the error:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          chandler
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/stop chandler server
### END INIT INFO
#
# chandler              This init.d script is used to start chandler.
#                       It basically just calls osafsrvctl.

# set environment variables
. /etc/default/chandler

# set local variables
RETVAL=$?
CHANDLER_HOME="/chandler"

# check input
case "$1" in
    start)
        if [ -f $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl ];
            then
                /bin/su chandler $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl start
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl ];
            then
                /bin/su chandler $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl stop
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/osafsrvctl {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Keep in mind that the above worked fine until some point where they didn't - no idea what has changed and why this is as it is now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `/chandler/bin/osafsrvctl` a shell script? And if so, post the its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this script runs with `/bin/bash`, check that the symlink `/bin/sh` is poiting to `/bin/bash` and not another shell (`/bin/dash` for instance). I had a similar problem transfering a bash script from an old Debian system to a newer one.

Try to change the first line by `#!/bin/bash -e`.

Comment: That did it... sh was linked to dash, changed it to bash, must have happened when I recently did a dist-upgrade, thanks!